# How can I use Express to render dynamic files?

Tags: node.js, dynamic, express

I'm looking to use Express to render raw strings as HTML, with the ability to reference static files in a specified directory (CSS, images, and other resources).

I've done a lot of research, but I haven't seen anything that approaches what I'm trying to do. For example, I thought perhaps writing a custom templating engine that only *pretended* to load a file would cut it, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: A code snippet would help a lot. If you have HTML as a string `res.send(myHtml)` and Bob's your Uncle. If your HTML has placeholders that need interpolation, all the templating modules provide APIs to render a string. Express provides the static middleware for serving static files, and URLs glue it all together.

Comment: @PeterLyons Unfortunately, the code I have is just an empty routing function, since I'm not sure where to go from there. Additionally, `res.send(html)` doesn't provide any of the requested files. For example, I get the error `GET http://localhost:3000/css/style.css 404 (Not Found)`, which is the crux of my problem.

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname))` to configure the static file server. Get a basic express app with the static middleware up and running and serving static files from the right directory as step 1. this is really first 2 minutes with express stuff.

Comment: @PeterLyons Yeah, it's definitely really basic, but I'm ashamed to say that I can't seem to wrap my head around it for some reason. :) I think I just had a little epiphany (`#mindblown`), though, in that using `express.static` doesn't necessarily mean you can only send static HTML files from your server--it's just more or less setting the directory requests will be directed to. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, you can send your dynamic HTML and that HTML can reference static files (CSS, images, fonts, etc). This is how pretty much every web application works. So the home page HTML is dynamic, but the logos, fonts, CSS, etc are just static files that live on disk and express sends them to the browsers.

Comment: @PeterLyons You helped me solve my question, so if you post your last few comments as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.
It can done in any other templating engine as well but here i am guiding you to implement same using EJS(Embedded Javascript).

Use Express Generator to create an ExpressJS app with EJS templating Engine.

command :

```
express --ejs AppName
```

For more information about express Generator refer to doc [here](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html)

Now EJS has tags such as :

```
 1. <% code %>   -  Code that is evaulated without "echo" it is not printed out.
 2. <%= code  %>  -  Code that is evaluated and printed out and escaped!
 3. <%- Code %>   -  Code that is evaluated printed out and not escaped!
```

So in your case you can use 3rd the third tag that i have mentioned above.

Render EJS views in the usual way from your route config:

```
res.render('index.ejs', {
  // data you want to pass ..
});
```

**Code sample**

Some time ago i was playing around with EJS, i developed a very small [blogApp](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/BlogApp) for practice.
You can look into [this](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/BlogApp/blob/master/app/views/home.ejs) view, line number 33, for more practical way of implementing same.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to use any current templating systems, as I essentially need to write my own.